# Inserting the image intro the text

Tags: graphics, wrapfigure

I am currently working on the project and trying to add images into the text. I want images to be wrapped. I am adding them after the paragraphs since otherwise Overleaf marks it as a mistake.

I am inserting it as:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{chicago.png}
    \caption{Chicago, USA}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

However, it ends up looking like this [image]

Comment: Could you please make a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get? (For the images you can use `example-image`. If you need dummy text, the `lipsum` package might be useful.) Please also add how you would like your output to look like (if needed you could also add a little sketch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overleaf is following the default wrapfig package rules, it matters not if the image is 20% or 80% of \textwidth. ONE image and adjoining paragraph at a time, if the paragraph finishes before the caption is cleared then another paragraph will be allowed alongside thus the next image will float down to the next following paragraph or overleaf to the next page if there is not enough space. In general you only control the attempted paragraph placement.

The rule is a second wrapfig will only begin...

**"if the paragraph is not wrapping around another figure"**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{mwe} % may be required one time to trigger on the fly example-image downloads
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\begin{document}
FIRST we have text and here we have text and here we have text and here we have CITIES continues
% implied end paragraph still needs
\par
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-A}
    \caption{Frankfurt am Main, DE}
\end{wrapfigure}
FRANKFURT we have text and here we have text and here we have text and here we have text and here we have text and here we have text and here we have text and here we have text and here we have text and here we have text and here we have text and here we have text and here we have text and here we have text and here we have text and here we have text and here we have text and here we have text and here we have text and here we have text and here we have text and here we have text and here we have text and here we have text and here we have text and here we have text and here we have text and here we have text AND\par SECOND FRANKFURTwe have text and here we have and here we have text and here we have text and here we have text AND
\newline
\par
CHICAGO we have text and here we have text and here we have text and here we have text and here we have text and here we have text  and here we have text  and here we have text and here we have text and here we have text and here we have text and here we have text and here we have text and here we have text and here we have text and here we have text and here we have AND \par
 \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.49\textwidth}
 \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{Chicago, USA}
\end{wrapfigure}
SECOND CHICAGO we have text and here we have and here we have text and here we have text and here we have text AND continues...
\par
\end{document}
```